# Access google cloud storage file on react app hosted with google app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a file on my cloud storage `https://storage.cloud.google.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/<FILE_NAME>`.

In my react app, I want to access it as follows:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src={url} type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

I'm able to do that if I sign in my email xyz@gmail.com which is listed as owner on my project but not from any other.

I have added my app engine's service account (`<PROJECT>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) with permissions "Storage Object Viewer" on the bucket but it doesn't help. Thoughts?

Error 403 with Service login flow. How can i confirm my app engine is actually using service account to authenticate?

my app engine has firebase initialized with the following and that works fine if that helps.

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Comment: If you don't mind anybody being able to access the file, then you can simply make the files public

Comment: App Engine is not accessing the file. The client (web browser) is accessing the file. Either make the file public or issue a Signed URL.

Comment: @JohnHanley yup ended up going the signed URL route. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What threw me off was that I could access with the "Owner" account without making it public. Tried a bunch of things to do the same for my service account but ended up going the signed url route

```
from google.cloud import storage
def get_signed_url(bucket_name, blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        os.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
    )
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=10),
    )
    return url
```